# Does git overwrite the .git directory after initialising an already created repository?

Tags: git

To further explain my question please consider the below scenario.

Step 1: I create a git repository.

```
$ git init myrepository
```

I get the output as :

```
  Initialized empty Git repository in /home/username/myrepository/.git/
```

Step 2: I move into the `myrepository` directory and see for a `.git` directory.

Step 3: After making a couple of files say file1, file 2, file 3 ... I then do the following.

```
$ git add file1 (similarly for file 2, file 3 and so on..)
```

and then do some commits for the above files created using

```
$ git commit -a - m "Message for commit"
```

Now my question is if at this point if I do

```
  $ git init
```

inside my current directory it shows me the message :

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/username/myrepository/.git/
```

My conclusion:

I am a beginner to learning git and it gives me an impression that this command overwrites whatever version control it was there in `.git` directory earlier so that means if I am working on a very large project every commit goes to waste.So am I thinking correct? Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: *"it gives me an impression ..."* -- have you read the [documentation of `git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init)? It tells you the facts, it doesn't let any room for impressions. Your impression is incorrect.

Comment: I am doing an online course. I find it hard going through documentation but then that's just a matter of preference.

Comment: Fortunately, Git has a good documentation. You can either run `git help` on your terminal or search it online on http://git-scm.com/docs/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for `git init`:

> **Running git init in an existing repository is safe. It will not overwrite things that are already there.** The primary reason for rerunning git init is to pick up newly added templates (or to move the repository to another place if --separate-git-dir is given).

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init

But given that hard drives do fail (and other bad things), I do suggest using a remote like Bitbucket, GitHub, or some other cloud based provider so that your local copy is not the only copy of your code.

Comment: So what does it mean that its "Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/username/myrepository/.git/" ?

Comment: I believe it is just telling you that it did something with an existing repository and did not create a new, empty one.

Comment: But this could also be an object lesson of creating user friendly and helpful messages.

Comment: So to add up if I am working in a local repository with large number of commits and I happen to type this command, then things are still in place ?

Comment: @user7841468 - When it says "Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/username/myrepository/.git/", it means that it reinitialized an existing repository, and that the repo metadata is in /home/username/myrepository/.git/.  "Reinitialize" is defined by the docs as quoted in the above answer.  It does seem you think `.git` is a file, whereas it's actually a directory, so perhaps that causes some of the confusion, but other than that I'm not sure what question remains about the message's meaning?

Comment: @user7841468 correct, nothing bad will happen to your exiting commits if you run `git init` again.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I just want a yes or no answer for as to whether my commits are safe in .git directory or are they all wiped off after I typed git init ?

Comment: @crashmstr Thank your sir.It was worth the effort but my confusion is clear now. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user7841468 - And yet when given a yes or no answer to that question, you continued with more questions; so apparently that *isn't* what you wanted, until it gave you a chance to be snotty toward those taking time out of their day to answer your questions.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I am sorry sir if I gave an impression like that, you are right I was rude and I should have chosen my words correctly.I have nothing but respect for guys like you who contribute to this community. Again I am sorry, my intention was to get a yes or no answer but not at the risk of being rude to you but please don't downvote my question because it will help many other folks who like to learn things from online videos and also to get in touch with talented folks like you.As for me, I am just a noob who is learning some new thing created by Linus.